# how to add ptr record in aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, pointers, amazon-ec2, dns

how to add ptr record in aws

```
   my smtp server is : admin.joinheresomething.com
  and my public ip is : 3.6.130.209 
  and i put A record point to : 3.6.130.209
```

please anyone help me to add ptr record in aws and i connected to cloudflare for ssl i requested for rdns in aws and they replayed :

The mapping for this reverse DNS entry is failing because the PTR record does not match the A record for that domain. We currently require the forward A record to match the PTR record for all reverse DNS entries.

You can either provide us with an alternate hostname or configure the A record for this domain to match the desired PTR record on your side.

If you would like to proceed with assigning a reverse DNS record to the Elastic IP, the first step would be to configure the A record for the domain to match the desired PTR record on your side.

Please follow the instructions at the link below to create the A record:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html

Once created, please reply back with the updated record information so that we can continue processing your request.

Regards,
Amazon Web Services

i don't understand how to setup ptr record

Comment: Is `3.6.130.209` your Elastic IP address?

Comment: no actually i changed last 3 digits